# Predictive model(s) to predict disease at a future time $t_1$, given the predictor and output values at time points $t_0,t_1$?

Tags: classification, categorical-data, predictive-models, biostatistics

Cross posted at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28926/predictive-models-to-predict-disease-at-a-future-time-t-1-given-the-predict, declaring it respecting the guidelines:

We've $N$ number of subjects (patients) measured TWO times, $t=t_0$ and $t=t_1, t_1 \gt t_0$, with the predictor and output variables as follows:

For the predictor variables, there're predictors $(x_1,x_2...x_p)$, measured both at $t=t_0,t_1$. Some of these predictors are directly related to biomarkers of a certain disease (e.g. flatness of nose), and some are not, e.g. marital status (single, married, divorced). Some of these $p$ predictors are categorial/discrete and the rest are continuous.

The outputs are $y, z$, with values measured at $t=t_0,t_1$. $y \in \{0, 1\}$. Here, $y=0$ means the patient is healthy, i.e. no disease, and $y=1$ means (s)he's diagnosed with the disease. Here, $z$ is a continuous variable, which is observed to be more for patient diagnosed with the disease ($y=1$) and less for healthy subjects ($y=0$).

**The problem is to build a predictive machine learning model so that we can predict $y,z$ at $t=t_1$, when we know $y,z$ at $t=t_0$.**

To predict $y$, I'm thinking of the following, please criticize my idea or suggest something new: 
***(1) Let $C_0$ be the set of all features in $\mathbb{R}^p$ so that $y=0, 0$ at $t=t_0, t_1$ respectively. And let $C_1$ be the set of all features in $\mathbb{R}^p$ so that $y=0, 1$ at $t=t_0, t_1$ respectively. Define a new categorical variable $Y$ to be $0,1$ for these two classes. 
(2) Then perform classification on $(C_0,Y_0)$ and $(C_1,Y_1)$. For a particular method, I'm thinking logistic regression, but is there intuitively a best choice without going to the cross-validation and testing?***

**BUT**, how do I predict $z$ at $t=t_1?$ I'm thinking of regression, but how exactly do I do this here?

If my idea is wrong, What kind of predictive model(s) should I use and why?

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: Please explain more about the underlying random process.  Which values do you think influence which other values?  Do you have any kind of model for how you think the predictors might influence $y,z$?